# User input to array element

Tags: c++

I have 20 players, each player can vote 3 times one of the 20 players.
If the first input "number" is 10,how can I add the votes to userToVote[10][vote],the 10th place from the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int userToVote[20][3];
int vote,number;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for(int z = 0;z<3;z++)
        {

            cout << "Hello player "<< i << "Insert the id you want to vote and the vote (0 or 1) ";
            cin >> number >> vote;
            cout << userToVote[number][vote];

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `++userToVote[number][vote];`

Answer (score 0):

Since a `player` can vote for 3 times.You can increment `userToVote[number][vote]` every time a vote is given.In this way, the vote can be incremented.You can change your code like this.

```
        cout << "Hello player "<< i << "Insert the id you want to vote and the vote (0 or 1) ";
        cin >> number >> vote;
        userToVote[number][vote]+=1;
        cout << userToVote[number][vote];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here you are not storing (not needed) which user voted to which one?
- So taking two-dimensional array is waste of space. Only 1-D array is enough.
- Even you want to store which player voted to particular, you shoud store **i** value.
- So intention of this program seems to be how many votes a particular player have?
- You can try in this way with 1-D array.
- If you want to store which player voted, you need to have 20x20 array. Because in worst case every player can vote(only one) a particular person.
  Based on the constraints it may increase.

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int userToVote[20]={0};
int number;
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for(int z = 0;z<3;z++)
        {
            cout << "Hello player "<< i << " This is your chance "<<z+1<<" to which player you want to vote?";
            cin >> number;
            cout << userToVote[number]++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if i am working only in that for this is working. But i want to save this to array list and print all the votes for every player.

Comment: Finally you just print userToVote array. Each ith index will have votes of i+1 player. (since index start from 0)